# makes CSS every text element darker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, less

I just realized that my entire Rails app was to pale, and would like a quick fix to make all text look, say, 120% darker. My trouble is, my text color values are all over the places. (If I just have a few text color values, then it could have been easier to find and replace all of them).

Is there a way to do this? I am not familiar with `less`, but I hope there's some quick fix that can help me out.

Comment: Posting your actual `CSS` or `Less` files would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I believe less is used to make all the css based on rules so it would be just as hard to implement it now as if you were to re-write your css.

For example if you set the base colour as @base: #ccc; then you can set other colours as a % like

```
 div { .box-shadow(0 0 5px, 30%) }
```

However, this would still force you to go through and replace all your css values with percents and also learn less... Good longterm solution, but not a quick fix.

I am not an expert on rails but if you were to go through all your files with a replace command and replace #fff with #ccc etc?

Answer (score 1):

Since your css is not less (or Sass)-based there is no straightforward way to accomplish this.  However, writing a script that would find all color values in css (using a regex) and replace them with darker color (i.e. decreasing all individual color values by some percentage) wouldn't be a hard thing to do.